# Android java read file pass result to method

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I think I am missing some basic principles of the java language, or programming in general.
I have read a text file with integers into a 2d array (which seems to work just fine) and pass the 2d array into a method from another class but when printing the results from there I get all 0s. I have a hunch this is something basic and simple that I have overlooked or am unaware of.

Here is where I populate the code in class Maps:

```
public void load() {
    mapWidth = 40;
    mapHeight = 32;
    //int[][] baseLayer = new int[mapWidth][mapHeight];
    baseLayer = new int[mapWidth][mapHeight];
    try {
        is = file.readAsset("maps/townMap.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("android", "could not load file");
    }
    scanner = new Scanner(is);
    scanner.useDelimiter("[\\s,\r\n]+");
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mapHeight; j++) {
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                        baseLayer[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
    testMap = new AndroidMap(mapWidth, mapHeight, baseLayer, tMapLayer2);
    currentMap = testMap;
}
```

Here is where I try copying the contents in class AndroidMap:
public class AndroidMap {

```
int mapWidth;
int mapHeight;
int[][][] map;

public AndroidMap(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int[][] baseLayer, int[][]midLayer) {
    this.mapWidth = mapWidth;
    this.mapHeight = mapHeight;
    map = new int[mapWidth][mapHeight][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapHeight; j++) {
            map[i][j][0] = baseLayer[i][j];
            map[i][j][1] = midLayer[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Some concrete code of how you populated, passed and printed the array, preferably in flavor of an SSCCE, would help in understanding your mistakes better. For example, perhaps you're just passing the wrong reference?

Comment: Basically 2d array in android is not recommended. You should go for 2 parallel arrays or different data structure.

Comment: Yes it would be nice to see some code. So we can see what classes you have used to do this with. Then we can make suggestions once we know what you are using.

Comment: @user802421 are 2d arrays not recommended in Android? They are usually no problem in Java. In fact parallel arrays are advised against in Java, there are much better ways than using parallel arrays in my opinion, more room for error using them.

Comment: @AdamJMTech I read from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#object_creation

Comment: I guess efficiency is an issue for mobile devices. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It seems everything is just fine. It's just when I pass the array as an argument into a method of another class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the inner while loop.

Comment: @semahan Just a heads up, you can mark you own answer as being the accepted answer. Although you may want to take a moment to expand your answer to explain why that part was wrong also.